# vba - Declare variables from elements of a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to declare variant variables from the elements of a dynamic array.

I have an array (arrWS) which contains the names of specific sheets which is populated manually, and I want to declare "N" range objects where "N" is the number of worksheets.

Sequence:
1- Declare an array containing some worksheet names ==> varAAA = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", ...)

2- Get the number of elements in this array

3- Then like that if possible:

```
Dim varBBB(1 To N)
For i = 1 to N
    varBBB(i) = Sheets(varAAA(i)).UsedRange
Next N
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you must `Set` object variables:

```
'1- Declare an array containing some worksheet names
' ==> varAAA = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", ...)
Dim VarAAAA
varAAA = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")

'2- Get the number of elements in this array
Dim N As Long
N = UBound(varAAA) - LBound(varAAA) + 1

'3- Then like that if possible:
'Dim varBBB(1 To N)
Dim varBBB() As Range
ReDim varBBB(1 To N)
'For i = 1 to N
For i = 1 To N
'varBBB(i) = Sheets(varAAA(i)).UsedRange
    Set varBBB(i) = Sheets(varAAA(i - 1 + LBound(varAAA))).UsedRange
    'Confirm that ranges have been correctly set
    Debug.Print i, varAAA(i - 1 + LBound(varAAA)), varBBB(i).Address
'Next N
Next
```

Comment: How can we refer to the cells in an array of range?

Comment: @RomcelGeluz However you want to, e.g. `varBBB(3).Cells(1,1)` or `varBBB(x).Range(myRangeVariable)` or ....  It's no different to using a non-array `Range` object, except that it is indexed.

Comment: Oh yes! Another reason not to use a 3D array, (I used to do this to represent the sheet with 3rdD). Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like,

```
Dim arrWS() As String
Dim iLoop As Integer

With ThisWorkbook
  ReDim arrWS(1 To .Sheets.Count)
  For iLoop = 1 To .Sheets.Count
    arrWS(iLoop) = .Sheets(iLoop).Name
  Next
End With
```

then you can use `Ubound(arrWWS)` to get the last index of the array.

You can now use this code to store each usedrange in the sheet,

```
Dim arrBB() As Variant
Dim arrHolder() As Variant

  ReDim arrBB(1 To UBound(arrWS))
  For iLoop = LBound(arrWS) To UBound(arrWS)
    arrHolder() = Sheets(arrWS(iLoop)).UsedRange.Value
    arrBB(iLoop) = arrHolder()
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response Romcel.. Your code will put all workbook's sheets in the array.. I need to put only specific sheets not all of them.. these sheets are specified in the code itself .. Then I want to declare range variable with the same name varBBB each for one sheet (varBBB(1) = Sheets(First Array Element).UsedRange, varBBB(2 = Sheets(Second Array Element).UsedRange))

Comment: Updated the post. You can disregard the first set of code and iterate trough the specific array of sheets using the second set of code. You need the `arrHolder()` to temporarily hold the array of `UsedRange`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Dim varBBB()
Redim varBBB(LBound(varAAA) to UBound(varAAA))
For i = LBound(varAAA) to UBound(varAAA)
    varBBB(i) = Sheets(varAAA(i)).UsedRange
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you Rory.. When I create the sheets array like that varAAA= Array("Sheet1", Sheet2", "Sheet4") your code gives me Subscript out of range error.